# how to read data from textbox using backbonejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

i want to read data from user input text box from the template and create a json object using backbonejs mvc framework.
here m using handlebars.1.0.0.beta.3, require js,backbone.marionette.min.
m having one template made of 4 user inputs text fields.

how do i start it ??
I m new to this.please help me

i want to read all text box data on submit

Answer (score 2):

there is no special way of doing it, you just use JQuery there.

Say if you have a form in template, on view have a event capturing submit event of that form. and read values of all input in that handler

```
 var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template:formTemplate, //which has a form
    events:{
       'submit form':'submitHandler'
    },
    submitHandler:function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var inputFields = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
       var valueMap = _.map(inputFields, function(elementName){
           var obj = {};
           obj[elementName] = this.$('input[name='+elementName+']').val();
           return obj;
       })
       console.log(valueMap);
    }
 })
```

Comment: m getting json objects in console as ..... 
yourName=Guddu&contact=123456&description=no need&city=hyderabad.

but i want json object as in valid format as....
{
  "youName":"Guddu",
  "contact":"123456",
  "description":"no need",
  "city":"hyderabad",
}

here m using $(":input").serialize() to take form data and conert into json object....

please help me from these

Answer (score 2):

Googling for 'backbone form submit' gives you pretty fair results, there is a gist among them:

https://gist.github.com/sbrekken/1391456

which is exaclty what you need.

The simpliest way to get those values is to use jQuery:

```
this.$('input[name=name]').val()
```

Node that `this.$` will search for `input[name=name]` within the scope of `this` view.

Comment: but here wew are using backbone js mvc structure...i have to go in that way only. how i read this one in view and convert to json object

Comment: @Guddyaaa the above gist is a pretty basic backbone example, if you can't figure that out maybe you should start with view basics first. Put to http://jsfiddle.net/ what you've done so far.

Comment: okay buddy,,,,thanks for ur vauable time...m new to this i dont know how to do n frm where shuld i start...

Comment: in this case: http://backbonetutorials.com/ definitely worth a look. As you're new to stackoverflow, if an answer helps you out or puts you in the right direction, don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Comment: this is router from where m calling controller....define([
    "backbone",
    "marionette",
    "routes/controller"
],
function (
Backbone,
Marionette,
Controller) {

    "use strict";
 var AppRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
 appRoutes: {
   // "": "showLoanSelection"
   "": "showForm"
   
        }
    });
 alert("in router");
 return new AppRouter({
        controller: Controller
    });
});

Comment: this is controller.....define([ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'marionette', 'app', 'views/appLayout', /* 'collections/loanCollection', 'modules/landingPageModule' */ 'modules/formPageModule' ], function ( $, _, Backbone, Marionette, oswarApp, AppLayout, // LoanCollection, formPageModule ) { "use strict"; return {  showForm: function(){ oswarApp.formPageModule.renderFormPage(); } }; });

Comment: but m getting error over here....oswarApp.formPageModule.renderFormPage(); .....no such property supported

Comment: use http://jsfiddle.net/ to create an example and share the link here